Why do `super` calls compile so much faster than `this` calls?
I am implicitly using webpack 5.88.2 (referenced by Cypress 13.8.0) on a project of mine which mainly consists of TypeScript files. According to
find . -name '*.ts' | xargs wc -l it's a good million lines of code.
In PowerShell I set $env:DEBUG="cypress:webpack:stats" to investigate the compile time.
According to grep -r super | wc -l there are 38187 calls to (protected) super methods (e.g. super.type("foo")). The webpack compile time is 24 seconds.
If I replace all those super calls with this calls (e.g. this.type("foo")), the compile time is 33 seconds instead.
This makes quite a difference to me, as webpack compilation happens again and again with each run of my tests.
Why do these 38187 calls matter so much in a million lines of code?
(And are there other tricks I should know?)
Note: My code does the same after the replacement, because those methods are not overridden so far.
